# Why does my heroku app keep crashing even if it works locally?

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

I've been looking everywhere online, but I can't seem to find an answer. I keep getting error code H10 with a status of 503, meaning it's crashing because of request timeout. However, I can't pinpoint where the issue is.

Here's my server.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const logger = require("morgan");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

require("./routes/apiRoutes.js")(app);
require("./routes/htmlRoutes.js")(app);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/workout", { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

And here is the error most recent error log:

```
2020-04-21T18:54:38.462341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=protected-depths-80302.herokuapp.com request_id=74846a7d-d9b0-49b7-a8ee-979d3bb75d6a fwd="73.248.13.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-04-21T18:54:38.678122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=protected-depths-80302.herokuapp.com request_id=5e304f76-b764-4984-baa9-bffea70d9bcf fwd="73.248.13.42" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Am I missing something in my server.js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the port variable which is set with process.env.PORT variable (or 3000 when is undefined ie working locally)

```
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`App running on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```